# While implementing dead-letter queue (DLQ), a channel error is throw

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

**channel error; protocol method: #method(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-dead-letter-exchange' for queue 'ecpauditchannel.ecpqueue' in vhost 'ecp-audit': received the value 'DLX' of type 'longstr' but current is none, class-id=50, method-id=10)**

The following are the configurations set in the properties file.

```
spring.rabbitmq.virtual-host=ecp-audit
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.ecpinputchannel.destination=ecpchannel
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.error.destination=ecpError
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.ecpauditinputchannel.consumer.auto-bind-dlq=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.dlq-ttl=5000
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> inequivalent arg 'x-dead-letter-exchange' for queue 'ecpauditchannel.ecpqueue' in vhost 'ecp-audit': received the value 'DLX' of type 'longstr' but current is none, class-id=50, method-id=10)

You can't change queue arguments once a queue is created.

> but current is none,

There is no `x-dead-letter-exchange` argument on the current queue.

> `auto-bind-dlq=true`

Causes this argument to be set.

You have to manually delete the existing queue (e.g. using the management console) to be able to create the new one with DLQ arguments set.

Comment: Gary thank you for your quick reply, however, I am confused because I am following the steps provided in the cloud spring documentation. https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/multi/multi__retry_with_the_rabbitmq_binder.html

Comment: Yes; but if the queue was already created once, without that property set, you will need to delete the queue first, e.g. using the Management console, so it can be created with the new properties.